# How to translate this MySQL command to SQLite command?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, mediawiki, password-recovery

I have a MediaWiki instance that uses sqlite database instead of MySQL. The [standard documentation on resetting password](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords) explains how to reset password for MySQL but not for sqlite database:

> MySQL salted (make sure both instances of "somesalt" are the same):
>
> ```
> UPDATE `user` 
> SET user_password = CONCAT(':B:somesalt:', MD5(CONCAT('somesalt-', MD5('somepass')))) 
> WHERE user_name = 'someuser';
> ```

How does one translate it to suitable sqlite command?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not show a command for SQLite because it has no built-in `MD5` function.

Also long as you need to change only a single password, you could compute the MD5 values manually on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/8425):

```
SELECT CONCAT(':B:somesalt:', MD5(CONCAT('somesalt-', MD5('somepass'))));

:B:somesalt:e565ddf094ec99d4963cb2cb3d803d82
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how sqlfiddle.com enters into the answer.  You've not shown OP how to calculate it there, nor could OP use sqlfiddle.com in their code.  They could just as easy use their own sqlite instance to try to figure out the calculation....which you also dont offer any help for.

Comment: Thanks.  Do anyone have any sense what that `somesalt` is?  Should I just use the value I see currently in the database?

Comment: See [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). You should use a new random value.